# What is AWS Prefix actually?

Tags: amazon-web-services, prefix

## Question

What/where is the definition of AWS Prefix?

### Background

While looking for a way to list S3 endpoint CIDR, encountered the word AWS **prefix list** but not sure what it exactly means and where the terminology is defined.

### Confusion

**Prefix** means a word placed in front. For S3, according to [Listing Keys Hierarchically Using a Prefix and Delimiter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingKeysHierarchy.html), it should be the starting path to an object.

However, apparently it refers to a IP address range. How come **prefix** is used for IP ranges? What is the history or reason?

[Terraform aws_prefix_list](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/prefix_list.html)

> This can be used both to validate a prefix list given in a variable and to obtain the CIDR blocks (IP address ranges) for the associated AWS service.

[describe-prefix-lists](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-prefix-lists.html)

> Describes available AWS services in a prefix list format, which includes the prefix list name and prefix list ID of the service and the IP address range for the service.

[AWS IP Address Ranges](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html)

```
SERVICE="S3"
REGION="us-west-1"
$ curl -s https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json | \
  jq -r --arg SERVICE "$SERVICE" --arg REGION "${REGION}" '.prefixes[] \
   | select(.service==$SERVICE and .region==$REGION)'

{
  "ip_prefix": "52.92.48.0/22",
  "region": "us-west-1",
  "service": "S3"
}
{
  "ip_prefix": "54.231.232.0/21",
  "region": "us-west-1",
  "service": "S3"
}
{
  "ip_prefix": "52.219.20.0/22",
  "region": "us-west-1",
  "service": "S3"
}
{
  "ip_prefix": "52.219.24.0/21",
  "region": "us-west-1",
  "service": "S3"
}
```

---

### Update

[Gateway VPC Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-gateway.html)

> Specify the VPC in which to create the endpoint, and the service to which you're connecting. **A service is identified by a prefix list—the name and ID of a service for a Region**. A prefix list ID uses the form pl-xxxxxxx and a prefix list name uses the form "com.amazonaws.region.service". Use the prefix list name (service name) to create an endpoint.

[what is the meaning of Prefix ?](https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/thread/59390)

> suppose you have a network like 10.5.10.0/24
>   so you will have the 10.5.10 prefix in that subnet from 1 to 255 and your network address will be 10.5.10.0

I suppose (10.0.0.0/24) means (Top 24 bit part of 32 bit IP) of a network that has 
 254 ip addresses from 1 to 254 (0 is network and 255 is broadcast). Prefix is top 24 bit and suffix (?) is last 8 bit. List of top N bit which identifies a network is a list of IP prefix.

Comment: *"Prefix means a word placed in front."*  Note that a *prefix* here is indeed a word -- a binary word -- with a length of *n* bits.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If what you are looking for is prefix list id for `vpc endpoint` like dynamodb/s3, then it is not related to IP or CIDR. As it is mentioned in the documentation:

> A prefix list ID is required for creating an outbound security group rule that allows traffic from a VPC to access an AWS service through a gateway VPC endpoint.

So if do not have prefix-list id in your security group outbout for ec2 or vpc-lambda, you will get **time out** when connecting to `dynamodb` or `s3`.

You can get the prefix-list by running

> aws ec2 describe-prefix-lists

```
{
    "PrefixLists": [
        {
            "Cidrs": [
                "54.231.0.0/17",
                "52.216.0.0/15"
            ],
            "PrefixListId": "pl-63c5400k",
            "PrefixListName": "com.amazonaws.us-east-1.s3"
        },
        {
            "Cidrs": [
                "52.94.0.0/22",
                "52.119.224.0/20"
            ],
            "PrefixListId": "pl-02ad2a6c",
            "PrefixListName": "com.amazonaws.us-east-1.dynamodb"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then you can put this `PrefixListId` into your security group outbound via aws web console. If you use terraform for different region, it could be something like:

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "MyService_to_DynamoDB_east" {
  count = "${ lower(var.region) == "us-east-1" ? 1 : 0 }"

  security_group_id = "${aws_security_group.MyService_Ext_Api.id}"
  description       = "DynamoDB"
  type              = "egress"
  protocol          = "tcp"
  from_port         = 443
  to_port           = 443
  prefix_list_ids    = ["pl-02ad2a6c"]
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "MyService_to_DynamoDB_west" {
  count = "${ lower(var.region) == "us-west-2" ? 1 : 0 }"

  security_group_id = "${aws_security_group.MyService_Ext_Api.id}"
  description       = "DynamoDB"
  type              = "egress"
  protocol          = "tcp"
  from_port         = 443
  to_port           = 443
  prefix_list_ids    = ["pl-0ca54061"]
}
```

Comment: So AWS automatically provide ready-baked prefix-lists for S3 and DynamoDB per region. But you're free to create your own too.

Answer (score 10):

The term prefix list comes from routing technology. An IP address in CIDR format has an IP prefix and a network prefix (10.1.0.0/16). The IP prefix is 10.1 and the network prefix is /16.

Therefore if you are using a list of IP addresses in CIDR format we call it an IP Prefix List.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I suppose "ip_prefix" field in JSON is not actually a prefix to be exact, but I understood now.

Comment: It is a prefix list if it is in this format "192.168.0.0/16". The "192.168" is the IP prefix in this example. Another example, "192.168.10.14/32". The IP prefix is "192.168.10.14". Looks strange at first, but you quickly learn to read them without actually thinking about it.

Answer (score 3):

## What is Prefix List in AWS VPC context

**Prefix List** is the IP ranges in CIDR format which are assigned to the VPC Gateway Endpoint (S3 or DynamoDB) in a region. It is region-specific.

For example, as of 24/Feb, 2020, the prefix list for DynamoDB in the us-east-2 region is "52.94.4.0/24" where **52.94.4** is the IP prefix and the network prefix is **/24** as explained by @John Hanley.  The IPs the VPC Gateway endpoint for DynamoDB can take is within 52.94.4.1 - 52.94.4.254 (AWS may have reserved some IPs).

```
$ aws ec2 describe-prefix-lists
{
    "PrefixLists": [
        {
            "Cidrs": [
                "52.94.4.0/24"
            ],
            "PrefixListId": "pl-4ca54025",
            "PrefixListName": "com.amazonaws.us-east-2.dynamodb"
        },
        {
            "Cidrs": [
                "52.219.80.0/20",
                "3.5.128.0/22",
                "3.5.132.0/23",
                "52.219.96.0/20",
                "52.92.76.0/22"
            ],
            "PrefixListId": "pl-7ba54012",
            "PrefixListName": "com.amazonaws.us-east-2.s3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Those prefix list has an ID and a name. We can specify **prefix list ID** in a VPC routing table and in a Security Group, but not in NACL. We need to use CIDR for NACL.

[image]

- [Gateway VPC Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-gateway.html)

  > You can**NOT** *use a prefix list ID in an outbound rule in a network ACL* to allow or deny outbound traffic to the service specified in an endpoint. If your network ACL rules restrict traffic, you must specify the CIDR block (IP address range) for the service instead. You can, however, use a prefix list ID in an outbound security group rule. For more information, see Security Groups.

### Terraform examples

#### NACL

- [Data Source: aws_prefix_list](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/prefix_list.html)

```
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "private_s3" {
  vpc_id       = "${aws_vpc.foo.id}"
  service_name = "com.amazonaws.us-west-2.s3"
}

data "aws_prefix_list" "private_s3" {
  prefix_list_id = "${aws_vpc_endpoint.private_s3.prefix_list_id}"
}

resource "aws_network_acl" "bar" {
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.foo.id}"
}

resource "aws_network_acl_rule" "private_s3" {
  network_acl_id = "${aws_network_acl.bar.id}"
  rule_number    = 200
  egress         = false
  protocol       = "tcp"
  rule_action    = "allow"
  cidr_block     = "${data.aws_prefix_list.private_s3.cidr_blocks[0]}"
  from_port      = 443
  to_port        = 443
}
```

#### Security Group as provided by @LeOn - Han Li in his answer.

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "MyService_to_DynamoDB_east" {
  count = "${ lower(var.region) == "us-east-1" ? 1 : 0 }"

  security_group_id = "${aws_security_group.MyService_Ext_Api.id}"
  description       = "DynamoDB"
  type              = "egress"
  protocol          = "tcp"
  from_port         = 443
  to_port           = 443
  prefix_list_ids    = ["pl-02ad2a6c"]
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "MyService_to_DynamoDB_west" {
  count = "${ lower(var.region) == "us-west-2" ? 1 : 0 }"

  security_group_id = "${aws_security_group.MyService_Ext_Api.id}"
  description       = "DynamoDB"
  type              = "egress"
  protocol          = "tcp"
  from_port         = 443
  to_port           = 443
  prefix_list_ids    = ["pl-0ca54061"]
}
```

## Access Control

[Why can’t I connect to an S3 bucket using a gateway VPC endpoint?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-s3-vpc-endpoint/) layouts comprehensive list regarding S3 VPC Gateway Endpoint and the prefix list ID and CIDR would play parts there.

- DNS settings in your VPC
   
  Important: DNS resolution must be enabled in your VPC (see Gateway Endpoint Limitations). If you're using your own DNS server, be sure DNS requests to AWS services resolve to AWS-maintained IP addresses.
- Route table settings to Amazon S3
- Security group outbound rules
- Network ACL rules
- Gateway VPC endpoint policy
- S3 bucket policy
- IAM policy

## References

- [Gateway VPC Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-gateway.html)

  > Specify the VPC in which to create the endpoint, and the service to which you're connecting. A service is identified by a prefix list—the name and ID of a service for a Region. A prefix list ID uses the form pl-xxxxxxx and a prefix list name uses the form "com.amazonaws.region.service". Use the prefix list name (service name) to create an endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Well even though question is answered regarding Prefix definition pertaining to VPC, I did not see answer to prefix definition related to S3 (beside CIDR related). Simply put in S3 if you have a folder Photos and it has yourpic.jpg file in it then it should look like this photos/yourpic.jpg. The part which is folder photos/ is called prefix in S3 Terminology. As mentioned in latest AWS Performance tuning guide for S3 we can use prefix to do parallelism and increase performance. Anyway I am still learning AWS so take it with a grain of salt. Check below link for reference.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/using-folders.html

Answer (score 0):

An AWS-managed prefix list is a way to add a single rule in an AWS Security Group that represents all the IP ranges for that service instead of having to enter every single range in the AWS IP ranges here:

https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json

For example, if you want to provide outbound access to S3 you would have to enter every IP range in that JSON IP ranges list to access S3 (or the ones in the region you're in if you are restricting access to a single region.)

With a prefix list, you create a rule in the security group and assign the prefix list instead as the destination.

You can also create your own customer-managed prefix list for your own list of IP ranges. I just wrote a blog post on how to do that on my medium Cloud-Security blog.